# Is there a way to get a callback when subscription changed in Huawei In App Purchase?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am implementing IAP to my application.

There is a flow to change/cancel already purchased subscription. To do that "Subscription management" page should be opened. It is possible by getting result from

```
iapClient.startIapActivity(inAppRequest)
```

and calling

```
startIapActivityResult.startActivity(activity)
```

Unfortunately, in this case no result is returned and no callback is invoked, thus changes in subscriptions are not known unless a request is performed.

Is there a possibility to observe changes in user subscriptions while app is running?

Or is it possible to get a result in a same way (in onActivityResult) when a product is purchased using

```
iapClient.createPurchaseIntent(purchaseIntentReq)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
obtainOwnedPurchases()
```

to query the current subscription. The returned subscription includes the current status of the subscription.

You can get more detail from : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/iapclient-0000001050137587-V5#ZH-CN_TOPIC_0000001050137587__section15126153542812